# How Do I use Handler in the following code to enable me to run JobScheduler

Tags: android, handler, android-jobscheduler

package comeagain.materialdesign.activities;

```
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.style.ImageSpan;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.oguzdev.circularfloatingactionmenu.library.FloatingActionButton;
import com.oguzdev.circularfloatingactionmenu.library.FloatingActionMenu;
import com.oguzdev.circularfloatingactionmenu.library.SubActionButton;

import java.util.logging.Handler;

import comeagain.materialdesign.Log.L;
import comeagain.materialdesign.Service.MyService;
import comeagain.materialdesign.extras.SortListener;
import comeagain.materialdesign.fragments.FragmentBoxOffice;
import comeagain.materialdesign.fragments.FragmentSearch;
import comeagain.materialdesign.fragments.FragmentUpcoming;
import comeagain.materialdesign.fragments.MyFragment;
import comeagain.materialdesign.fragments.NavigationDrawerFragment;
import comeagain.materialdesign.R;
import comeagain.materialdesign.views.SlidingTabLayout;
import it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTab;
import it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost;
import it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabListener;
import me.tatarka.support.job.JobInfo;
import me.tatarka.support.job.JobScheduler;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MaterialTabListener, View.OnClickListener {

    private static final int JOB_ID =100 ;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ViewPager mPager;
    private MaterialTabHost mTabHost;
    private SlidingTabLayout mTabs;
    private  ViewPagerAdapter adapter;

    public static final int MOVIES_SEARCH_RESULTS = 0;
    public static final int MOVIEE_HITS = 1;
    public static final int MOVIES_UPCOMING = 2;
    public static final int TAB_COUNT = 3;
    private JobScheduler mJobScheduler;

    private static final String TAG_SORT_NAME = "sortName";
    private static final String TAG_SORT_DATE = "sortDate";
    private static final String TAG_SORT_RATINGS = "sortRatings";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mJobScheduler = JobScheduler.getInstance(this);


        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                constructJob();
            }
        },30000);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
/*
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
*/
        NavigationDrawerFragment drawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        mTabHost = (MaterialTabHost) findViewById(R.id.materialTabHost);
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                mTabHost.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });
        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            mTabHost.addTab(
                    mTabHost.newTab()
                            .setIcon(adapter.getIcon(i))
                            .setTabListener(this)
            );
        }
        buildFAB();
    }
public void constructJob(){
    JobInfo.Builder builder=new JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID, new ComponentName(this, MyService.class));
    builder.setPeriodic(2000)
           .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED)
            .setPersisted(true);
    mJobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());

    }
private void buildFAB(){
        // in Activity Context
        ImageView icon = new ImageView(this); // Create an icon
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_new);
        FloatingActionButton actionButton = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this)
                .setContentView(icon)
                .setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.selector_button_red)
                .build();

// repeat many times:
        ImageView iconSortName = new ImageView(this);
        iconSortName.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_alphabets);
        ImageView iconSortDate = new ImageView(this);
        iconSortDate.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_calendar);
        ImageView iconSortRatings = new ImageView(this);
        iconSortRatings.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_important);

        // set background for all the buttons
        SubActionButton.Builder itemBuilder = new SubActionButton.Builder(this);
        itemBuilder.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selector_sub_button_gray));

        // build the sub buttons
        SubActionButton buttonSortName = itemBuilder.setContentView(iconSortName).build();
        SubActionButton buttonSortDate = itemBuilder.setContentView(iconSortDate).build();
        SubActionButton buttonSortRatings = itemBuilder.setContentView(iconSortRatings).build();

        buttonSortName.setTag(TAG_SORT_NAME);
        buttonSortDate.setTag(TAG_SORT_DATE);
        buttonSortRatings.setTag(TAG_SORT_RATINGS);

        buttonSortName.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonSortDate.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonSortRatings.setOnClickListener(this);
        //Add the sub buttons to the main floating action button
        FloatingActionMenu actionMenu = new FloatingActionMenu.Builder(this)
                .addSubActionView(buttonSortName)
                .addSubActionView(buttonSortDate)
                .addSubActionView(buttonSortRatings)

                        // ...
                .attachTo(actionButton)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Hey you just hit " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.Navigation) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Sub_Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.TabsWithLibrary) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityUsingTabLibrary.class));
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.VectorTest) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, VectorTestActivity.class));
            return true;
        }

        return onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(MaterialTab tab) {
        mPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(MaterialTab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(MaterialTab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //call instantiate item since getItem may return null depending on whether the PagerAdapter is of type FragmentPagerAdapter or FragmentStatePagerAdapter
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) adapter.instantiateItem(mPager, mPager.getCurrentItem());
        if (fragment instanceof SortListener) {

            if (v.getTag().equals(TAG_SORT_NAME)) {
                //call the sort by name method on any Fragment that implements sortlistener
                ((SortListener) fragment).onSortByName();
            }
            if (v.getTag().equals(TAG_SORT_DATE)) {
                //call the sort by date method on any Fragment that implements sortlistener
                ((SortListener) fragment).onSortByDate();
            }
            if (v.getTag().equals(TAG_SORT_RATINGS)) {
                //call the sort by ratings method on any Fragment that implements sortlistener
                ((SortListener) fragment).onSortByRatings();
            }
        }
    }


    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        /*private String tabs[] = new String[]{"Tab 1 ", "Tab 2 ", " Tab 3"};*/
        int icons[] = {R.drawable.ic_home_black_24dp,
                R.drawable.ic_library_books_black_24dp,
                R.drawable.ic_person_black_24dp,

        };

        /*String[] tabText = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);*/
FragmentManager fragmentManager;
        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            fragmentManager=fm;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int num) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (num) {
                case MOVIES_SEARCH_RESULTS:
                    fragment = FragmentSearch.newInstance("", "");
                    break;
                case MOVIEE_HITS:
                    fragment = FragmentBoxOffice.newInstance("", "");

                    break;
                case MOVIES_UPCOMING:
                    fragment = FragmentUpcoming.newInstance("", "");

                    break;
            }
            return fragment;
        }



        @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return TAB_COUNT;
        }
        @Override

        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs)[position];
        }
        private Drawable getIcon(int position) {
            return getResources().getDrawable(icons[position]);
        }
    }


}
```

I have tried almost every solution there is online trying to solve this problem. I want to implement the Handler in onCreate method, I have implemented as shown in the code but it brings out an error(Handler is abstract; cannot be instantiated ). Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

I ev gotten the right way to handle this, I had imported the wrong Handler class.

```
import java.util.logging.Handler;
```

which asked me to implement these methods

```
Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void close() {

    }

    @Override
    public void flush() {

    }

    @Override
    public void publish(LogRecord record) {

    }
};
```

So to solve my error I just changed this

```
import java.util.logging.Handler;
```

to this

```
import android.os.Handler;
```

Thank you all.